# Restart while loop based on date

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a **date** coming from a downloaded CSV file. I want to upload data to an external server. Only if the date coming from the downloaded CSV file is **equal** to today's date.

So far I've tried the below; but after the **else** the loop just ends. How can I restart the loop in order to check if the date has changed?

**Example:**

```
current_date = 2021-03-01
report_date = 2021-02-28 
daily_counter = 0


while current_date == report_date and daily_counter == 0:
   upload_datasource() //this is the upload function
   daily_counter = 1
else:
   //restart the loop, check date again.
   daily_counter = 0
   time.sleep(60)
```

How would you guys approach this? If at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use if conditional statement during looping.

For the example:

```py
report_date = 2021-02-28
daily_counter = 0

while True:
   current_date = get_date()
   if current_date == report_date and daily_counter == 0:
      upload_datasource() //this is the upload function
      daily_counter = 1
   else:
      daily_counter = 0
      time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, **you can achieve this using for loop** instead of while.
You can simply add the if condition inside the for loop to check if the data frame date matches the current date.

For your reference, I made a dummy CSV having date and Id and printed the value if data frame data matches with the "current_date" value. I have attached the screenshot below, You can take a look.[image]